# Docstring text substitution for nadvice macros `add-function` and `advice-add`

Tags: nadvice

Starting with Emacs 29, the doc strings of macros `add-function` and `advice-add` are constructed, using substitution of a common part into a `"<<>>"` placeholder.

`C-h f add-function`:

> ... ...  
> which we call `OLDFUN` here: 
>   `:around  (lambda (&rest r) (apply FUNCTION OLDFUN r))` 
>   ...  
> If `FUNCTION` was already added, do nothing.  
> ... ...

But when I looked at the source code:

```lisp
;;;###autoload
(defmacro add-function (how place function &optional props)
  "... ...
which we call OLDFUN here:
<<>>
If FUNCTION was already added, do nothing.
... ..."
  ...)
```

How does the `<<>>` in the docstring get replaced with regular text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text `<<>>` is processed by the function `nadvice--make-docstring` which is defined above the definition of `add-function` itself.

```el
(defun nadvice--make-docstring (sym)
  (let* ((main (documentation (symbol-function sym) 'raw))
         (ud (help-split-fundoc main 'pcase))
         (doc (or (cdr ud) main))
         (col1width (apply #'max (mapcar (lambda (x)
                                           (string-width (symbol-name (car x))))
                                         advice--how-alist)))
         (table (mapconcat (lambda (x)
                             (format (format " %%-%ds %%s" col1width)
                                     (car x) (nth 2 x)))
                           advice--how-alist "\n"))
         (table (if global-prettify-symbols-mode
                    (replace-regexp-in-string "(lambda\\>" "(λ" table t t)
                  table))
         (combined-doc
          (if (not (string-match "<<>>" doc))
              doc
            (replace-match table t t doc))))
    (if ud (help-add-fundoc-usage combined-doc (car ud)) combined-doc)))
```

In particular, the following form is substituting for that token if it was found in the text:

```el
(if (not (string-match "<<>>" doc))
    doc
  (replace-match table t t doc))
```

That function is then used like so:

```el
(put 'add-function 'function-documentation
     '(nadvice--make-docstring 'add-function))
```

This says that the lisp form `(nadvice--make-docstring 'add-function)` should be called to generate the `add-function` docstring dynamically, whenever it is requested.

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Function Documentation` for details on dynamic docstrings, along with `(elisp)Accessing Documentation` (which notes of the `function-documentation` property "if the value is not a string, it is evaluated").

Comment: Please explain what `(put 'add-function 'function-documentation '(nadvice--make-docstring 'add-function))` does

Comment: I think this comment should be added to your answer.  It is much more important than the definition of `nadvice--make-docstring`.

Comment: Answer updated.